# Not getting the right results for longest consecutive sequence

Tags: python, cs50

The longest consecutive sequence I'm getting is always 1. When I comment `run = 0` out the value doesn't reset properly and the resulting value is too high.

```
#find sequences
for y in range(len(headers)-1):
    x = len(headers[y+1])
    highest = 0
    run = 0
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        if (sequence[i:i+x]) == headers[y+1]:
            print(sequence[i:i+x])
            i += x
            run += 1
        else:
            if (run > highest):
                highest = run
            run = 0

        if (run > highest):
            highest = run

    results[y] = highest
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out myself.

```
#find sequences
for y in range(len(headers)-1):
    x = len(headers[y+1])
    highest = 0
    run = 0
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        if (sequence[i:i+x]) == headers[y+1]:
            #i += x
            while(sequence[i:i+x]) == headers[y+1]:
                run += 1
                i += x     
        else:
            if (run > highest):
                highest = run
            run = 0

        if (run > highest):
            highest = run
        run = 0

    results[y] = highest
```